# Set custom date field when new record created in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to be able to save a "followup date" for a student when a new student is created. This followup date needs to be 2 weeks in the future.

I have managed to do this in the controller as follows:

```
public function store(StudentRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $data['followup'] = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(2);

    $student = Student::create($data);

    // ....
}
```

However, this feels like a very long-winded way of doing things. I feel as though there ought to be a way to do it automatically on the Model with less code. I thought about using a Mutator, but that wouldn't work because the 'followup' field isn't actually being set from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `save` function in your model like this:

```
...
public function save(array $options = []) {

    if(!$this->exists){ # only before creating
        $this->attributes['followup'] = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(2);
    }

    return parent::save($options);
}
...
```

Comment: That works perfectly because it only executes it when the record is first created, which is exactly what I wanted.